# react-native / android - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have an react-native + redux app on android where I call some api like this:

```
// component.jsx
handleButtonPress() {
   this.props.actions.createUser()
}
```

And I have the actions:

```
//actions.js
export const createUser = (data) => ({
  type: types.CREATE_USER,
  payload: new Promise( (resolve, reject) => API.createUser(data, resolve, reject) )
})
```

And the API looks like this:

```
export const createUser = (data, resolve, reject) =>
  API.post('user', data)
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( json => json.error ? reject(error) : resolve(json) )
    .catch( e => reject(e) )
```

So when I press the button and call `handleButtonPress()` I recive the YellowBox error with:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

Can someone explain me please what I'm doing wrong?

I'm on MacOSX.

Comment: Can you put some `console.log()` in there so see how far it's getting? I don't see where the `register()` function is defined.

Comment: sorry, this.props.createUser()

Comment: Are you intentionally not passing data? it could be undefined in the call.

Comment: yes, its just an example, but I think the problem is that I reject in .then, because if no error, then everything is working fine

Comment: Where are you catching the reject error from the payload Promise? That could be your issue too.

Comment: .then( json => json.error ? reject(error) : resolve(json) ).catch( e => reject(e) )

Comment: No, that's catching the error inside the API call... but something has to handle when you call `reject(error)`. It would be the reject from the payload.

Comment: On second thought, where is `error` defined in `.then( json => json.error ? reject(error) : resolve(json) )`? Should it be `json.error`?

Comment: json object has a key error if something is wrong on server

Comment: I understand... but then it should be `reject(json.error)`... `error` alone would be undefined.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didint copy my code, I use json.error

Comment: Ok, great. So where are you calling `.then()` from the `resolve(json)`. I feel like there needs to be a catch added there too. This is for the Promise stored in the `payload` key.

Comment: @BradBumbalough I dont understand, http://jsbin.com/labifunori/1/edit?js

Comment: No... so you're passing the `resolve` and `reject` into `createUser`, that's great... where are you returning those functions? As in, when you call `resolve(json)` or `reject(e)`, where in your code is those methods returned?

Comment: @BradBumbalough I use promise-middleware for redux, I'm not calling anywhere

Comment: Ok, try replacing `reject(json.error)` with `throw new Error(json.error)`, so it gets caught in the `catch`.